# Running Spark Job on Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have written a custom spark library in scala. I am able to run this successfully as a spark-submit step by spawning the cluster and running the following commands. Here I first get my 2 jars by -

```
aws s3 cp s3://jars/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar .
aws s3 cp s3://jars/CustomJar .
```

and then i run my spark job as

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --jars RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:3.0.0-preview1,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0 --class com.activities.CustomObject CustomJar.jar
```

This runs my CustomObject successfully. I want to run the similar thing in Zeppelin, But I do not know how to add jars and then run a spark-submit step?

Answer (score 2):

You can add these dependencies to the Spark interpreter within Zeppelin:

- Go to  "Interpreter"
- Choose edit and add the jar file
- Restart the interpreter

More info [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/interpreter/spark.html#configuration)

*EDIT*
You might also want to use the `%dep` paragraph in order to access the `z`variable (which is an implicit Zeppeling context) in order to do something like this:

```
%dep
z.load("/some_absolute_path/myjar.jar")
```

Comment: How do i add a jar file, all i can see is dependencies section where i have to write artifact and exclude. I dont know how can i upload custom jar here.

Comment: The process is described in the documentation: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/manual/dependencymanagement.html

Comment: Also see my edit with an example on how to load a local jar.

Comment: %spark.dep is removed from Zeppelin 0.9 as well: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/interpreter/spark.html#dependency-management

Answer (score 0):

It depend how you run Spark. Most of the time, the Zeppelin interpreter will embed the Spark driver.

The solution is to configure the Zeppelin interpreter instead:

`ZEPPELIN_INTP_JAVA_OPTS` will configure java options
`SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS` will configure spark options